# Как убрать из кеша мини корзину woocomerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Так не получилось ,из консоли эти js тоже не могу обновить но выдает console.log('сброс');
но не обновляется

```
add_action('wp_ajax_cart_count', 'custom_cart_count');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_cart_count', 'custom_cart_count');
    function custom_cart_count() {
        echo WC()->cart->cart_contents_count;
        wp_die();
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts');
    function custom_scripts()
    {
        wc_enqueue_js( "
            $.ajax({
                url: '".admin_url('admin-ajax.php')."',
                data: {
                    'action': 'cart_count'
                },
                success: function(resp) {
                  console.log('сброс');
                  console.log(resp);
                }
            });
        ");
    }
```

Comment: Так у Вас в секции success, ничего не делается как выводится просто сообщение. Он получает кол-во товаров в корзине а потом присылает Вам сообщение 'сброс' и все. Если обновить страницу то все сбрасывается?

Comment: нет не сбрасывается,хочу сбросить,сбрасываеться только при добавлении нового товара

Comment: А у Вас какой кеш используется?

Comment: на WP вроде нет кеша

Comment: Так Вы же сами про него пишите или имеется ввиду просто обновить корзину и кеш пришёлся к слову?

Answer (score 1):

Задача вашего js скрипта в том, чтобы получить из php новый счетчик в корзине. Ок, вы его получили. А дальше вам надо по success не в консоль выводить инфу, а обновить html в мини-корзине тем значением count, который вы получили из php.